# Could UUID be used as a tracking number that user will use?

Tags: python, django, url, uuid

I am developing a Reporting system where a user can report another user for a variety of issues.

To display the report to the user, I am thinking of doing something like localhost:8000/reports/(UUID from model). Essentially use it as a tracking number that I will be displaying to the user so that they can track their reports.

Are there any reasons that I shouldn't do it this way (security? something simpler?)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A UUID is essentially a random 128-bit number, encoded into hexadecimal.  Nothing more, nothing less.  Their guarantee of uniqueness lies in the fact that 128 bits is a lot of bits.

You could probably get away with something smaller, but UUIDs are a quick and easy way to attach a unique id to a set of data